# Pyside2 - QOpenGLFunction object has no attribute glShaderSource

Tags: python, opengl, pyside, pyside2

I'm trying to use `QOpenGLFunctions` with `PySide2`. Everything was good until I tried to use `glShaderSource()` which appears to be missing in the `PySide2` implementation of `QOpenGLFunctions`

> AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtGui.QOpenGLFunctions' object has no attribute 'glShaderSource'

Furthermore, `glShaderSource` is also missing in the https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions.html

Isn't it a bug which is not resolved for a long time? Because I am using PySide `5.12` and the linked documentation is for `5.15`. Does anyone use `QOpenGLFunctions` with `PySide2`? Because how then you can use it without shaders?

---

```
from OpenGL import GL
from PySide2 import QtGui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication()
    off_screen = QtGui.QOffscreenSurface()
    off_screen.create()
    if off_screen.isValid():
        context = QtGui.QOpenGLContext()
        if context.create():
            context.makeCurrent(off_screen)
            
            ###
            f = QtGui.QOpenGLFunctions(context)
            shader = f.glCreateShader(GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            f.glShaderSource(shader, "") # <-AttributeError
            f.glCompileShader(shader)
            ####
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html#glShaderSource

Comment: @MudkipHacker I agree, this method is available in Qt C++ documentation but not in PySide2 https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions.html and that is the problem.

Comment: @JD. Oh I don't even know how I got to that page, just thought I clicked on your link and found it right there.